# backbone file list as an array

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Im new to backbone.

I'm trying to load a file list of a folder from REST API and save it to localstorage as an array, then later render the view using localStorage data.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/ask11/backbone-offline) backbone offline adapter

I managed to load data from REST to localStorage but I failed to save loaded data as an ARRAY.

It creates multiple records for each file in localStorage.

this is what i got,

```
file-1  {"id":"1", "folderid":"0001","name":"file number one","size":"1000"}
file-2  {"id":"2", "folderid":"0001","name":"file number two","size":"1000"}
file-3  {"id":"3", "folderid":"0001","name":"file number three","size":"1000"}
file-4  {"id":"4", "folderid":"0001","name":"file number four","size":"1000"}
file-5  {"id":"5", "folderid":"0001","name":"file number five","size":"1000"}
```

but this is what i needed

i only need one record per folder in localStorage.

```
file-0001    [{"id":"1", "folderid":"0001","name":"file number one","size":"1000"}, {"id":"2", "folderid":"0001","name":"file number two","size":"1000"},{"id":"3", "folderid":"0001","name":"file number three","size":"1000"},{"id":"4", "folderid":"0001","name":"file number four","size":"1000"},{"id":"5", "folderid":"0001","name":"file number five","size":"1000"}]
```

UPDATE:

```
directory.FILES = Backbone.Model.extend({});
directory.FOLDER = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        return this.storage = new Offline.Storage("folder-files", this, {
            autoPush: !0
        })
    },
    url: "api/folder/files", //this will return json data [{"id":"1", "folderid":"0001"},{...},{...}]

    model: directory.FILES
});

    var FOLDER = new directory.FOLDER();
    FOLDER.fetch();
```

Comment: Could you update your answer to include your model and the call you use to persist the data into `localStorage`?

Comment: Just checked on the backbone-offline Github page and saw that the author advises against using it currently: https://github.com/ask11/backbone-offline#disclaimer Perhaps you'd be better off with https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage, which is under active development

Comment: its working well with folder listing, only thing i couldn't figure out is saving json data as an array to one LOCALSTORAGE key.

Comment: There's some weird conventions in there... you're using `CONSTANT_CASE` for models and collections; there is a pretty strong convention of using `CamelCase` for both of those. Also what is `!0` doing in there?

Comment: i guess it's for `TRUE`, im not sure, that's what github page says. autopush enables syncing.

Comment: im kinda new to backbone. i found this issue, https://github.com/ask11/backbone-offline/issues/32

Comment: It is really hard to guess what is going on without the whole picture. If you could provide a [codepen](http://codepen.io/) with an actual fetch from your server (could provide faux data) replicating your issue we probably could help.